# Different performance in different windows user profile on previewing a report with crystal report XI

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a program written in VB6, which it uses crystal report XI release 2 runtime to generate report and it is installed on server windows NT version 6.0 Datacenter.

When I try to generate a report on the one of admin account it takes less than a minute to finish the work, instead of on another admin account it takes 20 minutes or more to generate the report.

I try to disable not working printer. I deactivate the antivirus.
But none of these works.
Have you got some tips to solve this problem?

Comment: if for one user, a report will run within some min and for another take time. Its shows that its related to database, not with report. Are you identify that how much record comes for both users?

Comment: Hello, it comes the same amount of row for both user

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the rpt using a specified printer. If one user profile has access to that printer while the other user doesn't, the runtime might waste time trying to locate that printer on the network. 
Change the report design (File, Page Setup...) to use no printer or default printer.

Comment: I had already set no printer in the report but it doesn't improve the situation.
Furthermore, rarely the performance came back to normality.